# Confusion over a trigronometric function

Tags: trigonometry, mathematical-modeling

[image]

I found 2 solutions

[image]

But they say it is:

[image]

It feels like there's a mistake in the shift here, I tested it on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/urjejmz3mh)  and the functions doesn't reflect the perihelion and aphelion years. Do you guys have a different understanding of the shift here? Thanks :)

Comment: How did you get your numbers 5 and 119? Why do you think their solution doesn't reflect the perihelion and aphelion?

Comment: if you look here https://www.desmos.com/calculator/urjejmz3mh, the 3d one is their answer, look at the minimum and max , they don't match their numbers of perihelion/aphelion dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confused because you are looking at the wrong section of the graph. Your $t$ is the time before/after the year 2000. So, your horizontal axis should be set to something like $(-50, 150)$, rather than something like $(1950,2150)$.

So, their answer is correct.